# SELECT rows with a new DISTINCT from a VARCHAR with CSV in it

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

I have an Oracle database table with a field called Classification which is VARCHAR. The VARCHAR is a CSV(using semi colons). Example:

```
;CHR;
;OTR;CHR;ROW;
;CHA;ROW;
;OTR;ROW;
```

I want to pull all the rows with ONLY a different value in the CSV from the others. It is ok if a row has a previously found value as long as it has a new different value.

For instance from the above dataset it would be:

```
;CHR;
;OTR;CHR;ROW;
;CHA;ROW;
```

If I do just:

```
Select DISTINCT Classification from Table1
```

I get rows that overlap distinct values due to the overall VARCHAR being Distinct.

I can get all the distinct values using:

```
select LISTAGG(val,',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY val ) as final
FROM
(
select distinct  trim(regexp_substr("Classification",'[^;]+', 1, level) ) as val 
  from Table1
   connect by regexp_substr("Classification", '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
  ORDER BY val
 )
```

which give me

```
FINAL
CHA,CHR,OTR,ROW
```

but am unable to make the link to pull out one record per unique value

Is this possible with SQL?

EDIT:  This is a database created by a large corporation and mine purchased the product. Now I am tasked with data mining the backend database for BI and have absolutely no control of the database structure.

No offence but I see many answers in the questions I have researched stating 'Do better database design/normalization' and while I agree MOST I have read have no control over the database and are asking for SO assistance with a problem because of this, not ridicule on bad database design.

I apologize if I offend anyone

There is no parent/child relationship. I cannot see the object layer but I assume these values are changed in the object layer before propagating to the client as there is no link to them in the actual database

Clarification:

I see 2 ways to solve this:

1: One select statement that pulls out 1 row based on a new unique value within the VARCHAR CSV(Classification)

2: Use my select statement to loop through and pull one row containing that value in the VARCHAR CSV(Classification)

Thanks all for the input. I upvoted the ones that worked for me. In the end I will be using the one I developed just because I can easily manipulate the output(to a csv) for what the analyst wishes.

Comment: And the reason why you store CSV in a VARCHAR field is...?

Comment: Storing a delimited list of values in a single column is Design Fail Number One.  While there may be a way to do what you want, it would be like "The Suite Joke" (look it up). You really, really, REALLY need to fix your data model.  Design your table to Third Normal Form. Your's doesn't even meet First Normal Form.

Comment: Please reformulate your question for a parent child table design This will eliminate the design objection and you can concentrate of the real problem (which you should describe more clearly). Do you need to eliminate parents with childs that are *subset* of childs of other parent?

Comment: Edited based on the 3 prior comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out this way and it runs fast(even once all my joins to other tables are added). Will test other answers as I can and decide best one(others look better than mine if they work as I would rather not use dbms_output)

```
DECLARE
 v_search_string varchar2(4000);
 v_classification varchar2(4000);
 
 BEGIN
    select LISTAGG(val,',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY val ) as final
    INTO v_search_string
FROM
(
select distinct  trim(regexp_substr("Classification",'[^;]+', 1, level) ) as val
  from mytable
   connect by regexp_substr("Classification", '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
  ORDER BY val
 );
 
 FOR i IN
     (SELECT trim(regexp_substr(v_search_string, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) l
     FROM dual
       CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(v_search_string, ',')+1
     )
     LOOP
        SELECT   "Classification"
        INTO v_classification
       
        FROM mytable
 
        WHERE "Classification"  LIKE '%' || i.l || '%'
       
        FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
      dbms_output.put_line(v_classification);
    END LOOP;
 
 
 END;
```

Comment: Selecting my answer as in the end it is only because it is the easiest to manipulate IMO

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to approach it:

- Assign row numbers to the original CSV data
- Split the CSV -> rows
- Now assign the split CSV values row numbers, sorted by the CSV ordering from the first step
- Return any rows where the row number for the previous step = 1
- Return the distinct list of CSVs

For example:

```
with tab as (
  select ';CHR;' str from dual union all
  select ';OTR;CHR;ROW;' str from dual union all
  select ';CHA;ROW;' str from dual union all
  select ';OTR;ROW;' str from dual 
), ranks as (
  select row_number() over ( order by str ) rn, tab.* from tab
), rws as (
  select trim ( regexp_substr(str,'[^;]+', 1, level ) ) as val, rn, str
  from   ranks
  connect by regexp_substr ( str, '[^;]+', 1, level ) is not null
  and prior rn = rn
  and prior sys_guid () is not null
), rns as (
  select row_number () over (
           partition by val
           order by rn
         ) val_rn, r.*
  from   rws r
)
  select distinct str
  from   rns
  where  val_rn = 1;
  
STR             
;CHA;ROW;        
;OTR;CHR;ROW;    
;CHR;
```

Comment: Nice solution covering all the advanced techniques and the necessary magic;)

Comment: Just finished testing this solution. It is strange in that it outputs all 70 unique rows but in 7 groups looking like your 1 group but larger

Comment: @Pearl - I'm not sure what you mean by that

Comment: Where yours says STR then lists the rows, mine does that(prints the STR) 7 times but appears to capture all the rows across the 7(each one contains 11 except the last). Maybe its a SQL Developer thing

Comment: This one solves my posted problem but is so advanced that I am having trouble adding the JOINs to other tables for the final output. It is the fastest solution ive tested

Comment: yeah, still not sure what's going on there! When it comes to the joins it may be best to post a new question

Answer (score 1):

This is an ad Hoc solution proposal if the generic answer yields a suboptimal performance and some restrictions are fullfiled:

- all the keys have a fixed length
- the maximal number of the keys is known

Than to parse the CSV string you may use this query (add further `UNION ALL` for longer strings)

```
with tab as (
  select ';CHR;' str from dual union all
  select ';OTR;CHR;ROW;' str from dual union all
  select ';CHA;ROW;' str from dual union all
  select ';OTR;ROW;' str from dual 
), tab2 as (
select str, substr(str,2,3) val  from tab union all
select str, substr(str,6,3) val  from tab where substr(str,6,3) is not null union all
select str, substr(str,10,3) val  from tab where substr(str,10,3) is not null)
select * from tab2;
```

which results in

```
STR           VAL         
------------- ------------
;CHR;         CHR         
;OTR;CHR;ROW; OTR         
;CHA;ROW;     CHA         
;OTR;ROW;     OTR         
;OTR;CHR;ROW; CHR         
;CHA;ROW;     ROW         
;OTR;ROW;     ROW         
;OTR;CHR;ROW; ROW
```

Now you need only to find the *first occurence of each  key and get all distinct strings with this first occurence*.

I'm reusing the approach from the solution of [Chris Saxon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63924949/4808122)

```
with tab as (
  select ';CHR;' str from dual union all
  select ';OTR;CHR;ROW;' str from dual union all
  select ';CHA;ROW;' str from dual union all
  select ';OTR;ROW;' str from dual 
), tab2 as (
select str, substr(str,2,3) val  from tab union all
select str, substr(str,6,3) val  from tab where substr(str,6,3) is not null union all
select str, substr(str,10,3) val  from tab where substr(str,10,3) is not null),
tab3 as (
select STR, VAL,
row_number() over (partition by val order by str) rn
from tab2)
select distinct str
from tab3
where rn = 1
```

Comment: I like this approach and works for my sample however the number of choices is variable with a believed maximum of about 70

Comment: @Pearl 1) calculate the maximal number of keys using `max(length())` 2) write a query that generates the `UNION ALL`select for this maximal count 3) compare performance. I bet you will beat the `connect by` and `regexp`  people at least 1 : 10. Variable count is not a problem as it leads to `NULL`s that are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You were very close since you had already gotten the list of distinct values. Instead of combining them with LISTAGG, you can use that list to find a row that contains that unique value. Below are two separate queries that will return a Classification for each unique value. You can try them both and see which performs better based on the data you have in the table.

#### Query Option 1

```
WITH
    table1 (classification)
    AS
        (SELECT ';CHR;' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT ';OTR;CHR;ROW;' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT ';CHA;ROW;' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT ';OTR;ROW;' FROM DUAL),
    dist_vals (val)
    AS
        (    SELECT DISTINCT TRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (classification,
                                                  '[^;]+',
                                                  1,
                                                  LEVEL))    AS val
               FROM Table1
         CONNECT BY LEVEL < REGEXP_COUNT (classification, ';'))
SELECT val, classification
  FROM (SELECT dv.val,
               t.classification,
               ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY dv.val ORDER BY t.classification)     AS occurence
          FROM dist_vals dv, table1 t
         WHERE t.classification LIKE '%;' || dv.val || ';%')
 WHERE occurence = 1;
```

#### Query Option 2

```
WITH
    table1 (classification)
    AS
        (SELECT ';CHR;' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT ';OTR;CHR;ROW;' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT ';CHA;ROW;' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT ';OTR;ROW;' FROM DUAL),
    dist_vals (val)
    AS
        (    SELECT DISTINCT TRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (classification,
                                                  '[^;]+',
                                                  1,
                                                  LEVEL))    AS val
               FROM Table1
         CONNECT BY LEVEL < REGEXP_COUNT (classification, ';'))
SELECT dv.val,
       (SELECT classification
          FROM table1
         WHERE classification LIKE '%;' || dv.val || ';%' AND ROWNUM = 1)
  FROM dist_vals dv;
```

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong but I run it with your table1 AS and it runs fine, take the table1 AS portion out and change the columns/tables to match mine and it just hangs forever, I have to kill the process

Comment: Have you tried both options? If you run just the query within the dist_vals common table expression, does that return relatively quickly or does that take a long time as well?  How many rows are in your "table1"?

Comment: Running option 2 now, been about 10 minutes.  I have not just run the dist_vals query without the second select but will.  There are millions of rows I believe however my query I posted runs in less than 30 seconds.

Comment: My mistake this table only has 210k rows without the joins.  I ran it without the final select and it still just never returns....strange...